# racket - remove non-alphanumetic characters from a string

Tags: racket

How to remove non-alphanumeric characters from a string? I only want to keep numbers and letters, and have thought of building a list of all non-alphanumeric characters and check if each character of the string is a member of the list

Comment: Please post your code, and any restrictions you have on what you can use. Also provide sample inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a list of characters, filter using the `alphanum?` predicate, then convert back to a string.

```
(define (remove-non-alphanum s)
  (list->string (filter alphanum? (string->list s))))

(define (alphanum? c)
  (or (char-numeric? c)
      (char-alphabetic? c)))
```